# Как вывести данные из MySQL при помощи PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица `news`, в ней 5 полей `id, text, title, author, date`. Необходимо вывести на странице эти данные. У меня никак не получается это сделать: все время какие-либо ошибки. Пробовал использовать функцию `mysql_fetch_assoc`, но что-то, как ее применять, я не очень понял постоянно - одна и та же ошибка `expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean`.
Я, конечно, понимаю, что это значит, но вот как исправить - нет...

```
$news = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news` ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($news, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($row as $col_value) {
        print "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вообще-то все очень просто, функций для работы с MySQL из PHP много (смотрите документацию).

Главное, что надо понимать про вывод данных из БД - это то, что это *две разные операции*. Сначала получаем данные из БД, а потом их выводим.

Для начала нам понадобится файл, в котором устанавливается соединение с БД (чтобы не писать его в каждом файле), db.php:

```
<?php
$db_host=''; // ваш хост
$db_name=''; // ваша бд
$db_user=''; // пользователь бд
$db_pass=''; // пароль к бд
// включаем сообщения об ошибках
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
// коннект с сервером бд
$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name); 
// задаем кодировку
$db->set_charset("utf8mb4");
```

Следующий файл будет получать данные

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `table_name`'); // запрос на выборку
$data = [];
// получаем все строки в цикле по одной и записываем в массив
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $data[] = $row
}
//Подключаем файл с HTML шаблоном
include 'template.php';
```

И в отдельном пишем весь HTML, в котором и выводим все данные

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
<p>
    Запись id=<?= htmlspecialchars($row['id']) ?>
    Текст: <?= htmlspecialchars($row['text']) ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Ваш код:

`$news = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($news, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { //echo $row['title']; 
    foreach ($row as $col_value) {
        print "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
}`

Уберите `MYSQL_ASSOC` из `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Выводим данные, и удивляемся, если данные почему-то не вывелись. Где проверки на ошибки? А вдруг, у вас подключение не удалось? Ошибки нужно не глушить, а обрабатывать

Answer (score 2):

Позволю себе запостить пример, приведенный выше, немного исправленный, с использованием `mysql`, который [не рекомендуется](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php) к использованию:

```
$sdd_db_host=''; // ваш хост
$sdd_db_name=''; // ваша бд
$sdd_db_user=''; // пользователь бд
$sdd_db_pass=''; // пароль к бд
$conn = mysql_connect($sdd_db_host,$sdd_db_user,$sdd_db_pass); // коннект с сервером бд
if(!$conn)
{
    throw new Exception('Не удалось подключиться к базе данных! Проверьте параметры подключения');
}
if(!mysql_select_db($sdd_db_name, $conn)) // выбор бд
{
    throw new Exception("Не удалось выбрать базу данных {$ssd_db_name}!");
}
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table_name`', $conn); // запрос на выборку
if(!$result)
{
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Не удалось выполнить запрос к БД, код ошибки %d, текст ошибки: %s', mysql_errno($conn), mysql_error($conn)));
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<p>Запись id='.$row['id'].'. Текст: '.$row['text'].'</p>';// выводим данные
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$resul = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$ar = mysql_fetch_array($resul);
do
{
echo "".$ar[news]." | ".$ar[date]."";
}
while ($ar = mysql_fetch_array($resul));
```