# получение данных из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно вывести только конкретную информацию о пользователе. Например Здравствуйте: <имя>. У меня все имена выходят, каким образом это можно контролировать? 
Попробовал как тут описано:
[Как вывести данные из MySQL при помощи PHP?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/137194/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-mysql-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-php/795064?noredirect=1#comment1254244_795064)
но выходит вся информация, а нужна только о конкретном пользователе, чтобы отдельно каждого приветствовали по имени. Спасибо.

Comment: @axmed2004 [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/213987)

Answer (score 1):

Получайте ассоциативный массив с данными пользователя и дальше выводите то, что вам нужно.

Например:

```
$req = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$user_id'");
if (mysql_num_rows($req)) {
   $user_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($req);

   echo 'Здравствуйте: ' . $user_data['name']; // Выводим только имя
}
```

Comment: детский вопрос, но все же, куда прописать $user_id, потом как у меня его нет. Я сделал так, но выходят все имена. Спасибо.

Comment: $user_id - это уникальный ид вашего юзера в БД по которому вы хотите получить информацию)