# Доступ к БД сайта

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, пароль, password

Каким образом можно подключиться к БД сайта без указания пароля? (`$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);`, `$db_pass`) (пользователю не должно быть видно значение переменной `$db_pass`,чтобы пользователь не мог поменять данные из базы данных).
P.S. как без указания переменной `$db_pass` в операторе `$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);` подключиться к базе данных.
Этого в [Как вывести данные из MySQL при помощи PHP?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/137194/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-mysql-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-php) не написано.

Comment: Пароль и так не виден "пользователю, скачавшему сайт интернет магазина". Так что вопрос бессмысленный. подключайся с пролем

Comment: @Ипатьев но пользователь будет видеть в коде значение `$db_pass`, а необходимо, чтобы пользователь не знал пароля.

Comment: Не будет он ничего видеть. ты вот много увидел, скачав свой ДНС шоп?

Comment: @Ипатьев для подключения к базе данных необходимо указать пароль (`$db_pass`), который заранее должен быть указан в коде.

Comment: Надо. указывай. И ради бога, старайся читать что тебе пишут. Иначе нет смысла задавать вопросы. Почитай [как работает РНР](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke) и в частности ГДЕ работает РНР и ЧТО возвращает запросившему сайт клиенту

Comment: @Ипатьев вы написали только Рекомендую почитать вот эту историю про маленького мальчика и яблоко. А как обойтись без пароля (переменной `$db_pass`) не написали.

Comment: я написал это **не тебе!** про мальчика я написал **другому человеку**. А тебе я написал третьим комментарием сверху: **Не будет пользователь ничего видеть**. ЧТО ЗДЕСЬ НЕЯСНО?

Comment: а тебе я написал вот эту ссылку: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke где объясняется, ПОЧЕМУ пользователь ничего не увидит. Прочти её пожалуйста ради бога перед тем как задавать свой вопрос в 50-й раз

Answer (score 0):

Решение вашей проблемы - сертификаты X509.
Авторизация без пароля.
Ссылки на документацию:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-rsa-files-using-mysql.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-encrypted-connections.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html

Comment: Рекомендую почитать вот эту историю [про маленького мальчика и яблоко](http://phpfaq.ru/humor/anecdotes#apple)

Comment: @Ипатьев Как я понял, автор что-то продает и хочет сделать что-то вроде реферальной системы партнерки, раздавая скрипт с доступом к базе товаров с актуальным наличием.

Comment: Да ничего он не хочет, у него вопросы уровня "как вывести данные из БД в браузер" (буквально). И в любом случае партнерки никогда не дают доступ к БД, все делается через АПИ

Comment: @Ипатьев Вы правы, автор не имеет должного опыта для реализации таких сложных вещей. Процесс получения опыта тернист, состоит из череды многих-многих неудачных решений и прочих фейлов.

Comment: @Ипатьев поясните как это делается через АПИ (ведь все равно необходима информация для доступа пользователя к информации, хранящейся в БД).

Comment: @myaccount тебе это вообще не надо, дядя говорит совсем о другом

Comment: @Ипатьев 
есть пользователь, есть база данных, пользователь должен подключиться к базе данных, для этого пользователь должен указать пароль для доступа к базе данных, который вводится в некоторой форме ввода и сравнивается с записями из другой базы данных. Но для сравнения с паролем из базы данных, необходимо указать пароль для подключения к ней. Откуда берется пароль для доступа к базе данных, для доступа к ней?

Comment: @myaccount ну какая ж каша в голове. **пользователь сайта не соединяется с базой данных!!!** сайт САМ соединяется с базой данных, и выдает информацию пользователю.

Comment: @Ипатьев хорошо сам сайт. Но для этого в коде сайта должна присваиваться переменная пароля `$db_pass` и пользователь, который скачает страницу (Сохранить страницу как) будет видеть значение этой переменной.

Comment: @myaccount **я тебе уже писал об этом**. попробуй сам "скачать (сохранить страницу как)" и потом доложишь о результатах, что ты там увидишь. приступай

Comment: @Ипатьев Так я и задаю вопрос как раз по это: как без указания переменной `$db_pass` в операторе `$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);` подключиться к базе данных.

Comment: @Ипатьев персональное спасибо за анекдоты :) Про таракана сейчас в тему мне зашел.