# Использование php переменной в html

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, вёрстка

Как получить доступ к php переменной выборки данных $row = $result->fetch_assoc() (см. [Вывод данных mysql при помощи php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/137194/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-mysql-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-php)) и вывести значения этой переменой в html (блоке div)?

Comment: Вывести её там `<?=$variable?>`?

Comment: @myaccount тебя устраивает информация по ссылке, или что-то ещё непонятно?