# Изменение пароля из SQL при помощи php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу изменить пароль в SQL.

```
<form action="chp.php" method="POST">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" name="old_password" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" name="new_password" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

php:

```
require_once 'connect.php';
$id = $_SESSION['user']['id']; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$hash = $user['user']['password'];
$oldPassword = $_POST['old_password'];
$newPassword = $_POST['new_password'];
if (password_verify($oldPassword, $hash)) {
    $newPasswordHash = password_hash($newPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $query = "UPDATE users SET `password`=$newPasswordHash WHERE id=$id";
    mysqli_query($connect, $query);
} else {
    echo "no";
echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($user);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: id - точно должен быть с `'`? У вас указано, что вы ищите id-строку, а должно быть id-число. Я про строку `$query = "UPDATE users SET ...`

Comment: Изменил. Ничего не получилось. Не могу даже через `var_dump();` вывести `$hash` из бд. Изменил код.

Comment: А зачем вы убрали php-код из вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$zsqlserver.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $pass);
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id= :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->fetch();

$hash = $user['password'];
$oldPassword = $_POST['old_password'];
$newPassword = $_POST['new_password'];

if (password_verify($oldPassword, $hash)) {
    $newPasswordHash = password_hash($newPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("update users SET password = :hash where id = :id"); 
    $stmt->bindParam(':hash', $newPasswordHash);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
        
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```

У вас какой-то уникальный алгоритм хеширования пароля в методе password_hash? Если нет, то в запросе update можно конкретно указать алгоритм хеширования, например

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("update users SET password = md5(:str) where id = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':str', $newPassword);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: алгоритм - md5. Сейчас проверю код. спасибо!

Comment: Отличное решение - сделать всё через параметры. Который раз уже не замечаю этого)

Comment: Проблема не решилась(

Comment: @mrkpr, со стороны php ошибок не вижу. В чем у вас затруднение? php файл вообще вызывается?

Comment: А у вас из БД данные вообще выводятся? Может проблема на стадии ещё подключения? Попробуйте ради теста вывести данные из таблицы. Пример, как это сделать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/137194/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-mysql-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-php?rq=1

Comment: @Frehzy, у него походу проблема с путями. Его форма не может найти файл chp.php  текущей директории. По этому его попытки вывести var_dump ничего не дают. И вообще вопрос, а где он смотрит вывод.

Comment: var_dump выводится. и значения из бд тоже. не знаю из-за чего проблема(

Comment: @mrkpr, если у вас выводится var_dump в вашем коде, который вы предоставили. То у вас не проходит условие password_verify($oldPassword, $hash), т.к. ваш var_dump выводится в else.